# Cakephp - Related table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.x

in the view method, I downloaded from the database all related students with the Courses table, adding pagination.

```
$this->paginate = [
        'order' => ['id' => 'desc'],
        'conditions' => ['Students.course_id =' => $id]
    ];
    $students = $this->paginate($this->Students);
    $this->set(compact('students'));
```

In the view (view.ctp), I display the whole table thanks to foreach. In the first column I would like the order number to be displayed. I tried to use $ key with foreach, but if I go to the other side, the numbers are zeroing, and I can not use ID.

```
<?php foreach ($students as $key => $student): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($key) ?></td>
```

In want something like this:

Page 1

```
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      LP    |     ID    |    NAME       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      1     |     5437  |    Mark       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      2     |     67    |    John       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      3     |     12    |    Lisa       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      4     |     63    |    John       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      5     |     657   |    Lisa       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
```

Page 2

```
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      LP    |     ID    |    NAME       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      6     |    5431   |    Michael    |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      7     |   36554   |    Lara       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      8     |     99    |    Anne       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      9     |     76    |    Luke       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
|      10    |     351   |    Chris      |
|------------|-----------|---------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is because $key is array index, not record number. each time paginate page is generate, array key is start from 0 (zero). To get record number, you must change h($key) with ($key+1)+($limit*($page-1))

** **update** **

$page = number of paginate page you want to show

$limit = number of records each paginate page.

Answer (score 0):

`$key`, in this case, is just an index of array element, so its values will be the same on every page. If you need to output some id related to your record, you have to use field from database.